# Orthogonality of Legendre polynomials with logarithmic functions

Tags: integration, orthogonality, legendre-polynomials

I have to find the value of this integral:
$\int_{-1}^1  \ln(1-x)*P_3(x)\,dx$

where $P_3(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial.

I thought I can write $\ln(1-x)$ as a summation of Legendre polynomials and then use the orthogonality relation to find the answer. That didn't really work, the closest I got was to:

$\ln(1-x)$=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(1)*x^n$ and that's not getting me anywhere.

Is this the right track of thought? Or is this question done in an entirely different method?

P.S The answer is $\frac {-1}6$

Comment: Writing a transcendental function as polynomial sounds difficult. How are Legendre polynomials defined?

Comment: Got it! Replace it by Rodrigues' formula and use integration by parts 3 times

Comment: Yes to consider the differential equation properties of these functions can be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help !